# Restore MULTIPLE files deleted from one commit to their state in previous commit (in bulk)?

Tags: git

I've been searching this for a little bit and, apologies, I'm sure the answer I need is already somewhere but I am unable to find the exact answer I want for **multiple** files. The answers I've found only describe reverting individual file paths.

I have hundreds of files across different directories of my repo that were deleted by someone in a specific git commit.

```
5678a22cbf20f2571fe8d37d8a8cc42ba7f89c62 - commit where files were deleted
309c00b621e696b138c80f7db321bb33980067f6 - commit I want to restore those deleted files to
```

I can get a list of the files that have been deleted in the last commit with:

```
git log --diff-filter=D -n 1 --summary
```

This gives me an output like:

```
delete mode 100755 path/to/file.js
delete mode 100755 path/to/another/file.css
```

I can revert individual files with:

```
git checkout 309c00b621e696b138c80f7db321bb33980067f6 path/to/file
```

But how do I restore ALL the deleted files from that commit in bulk?

My end goal is to have the reverted files as Uncommitted changes in my working copy.

Thanks in advance!

(sidenote: I am also using SourceTree if that has any tricks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost solved it yourself:

```
git log --name-only --diff-filter=D -n 1 --summary | while read file; do
    git checkout 309c00b621e696b138c80f7db321bb33980067f6 "$file"
    git reset "$file" # so that it shows as uncommitted
done
```

You should consider amending the revision where they were deleted if it was a real mistake so that history doesn't get busted by that deletion..... but, of course, rewriting history is always a thing that has consequences that have to be weighted in to decide if it's worth it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I type that in, it's looping through all the files but I'm getting this output on each file:
`error: pathspec 'delete mode 100755 path/to/file/file.js' did not match any file(s) known to git`
`fatal: ambiguous argument 'delete mode 100755 path/to/file/file.js': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`
Do I need to exclude the "delete mode 100755" part that's messing up the filepath?

Comment: Oh, my bad. I though you were getting a list straight (IOW, I copied/pasted the command you provided without thinking about it). Let me correct it.